# Unable to access cookie due to CORS policy in my backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios, cors

I created mern stack react app, using express and nodejs as a backend service. I am trying to create a login system for my app, using jwt inside of a cookie as a credential.I am working with axios,in the front, in order to create end points for my callings,also using redux toolkit to manage everything. I succeeded in making the registration but having an issue with the login. When I am trying to connect some user I created to the app, and get the cookie and the token, I am getting the following error in my console:
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
I am stuck on this particular error for a long period of time with no solution.
I will be very thankful if anyone could help.

**My api component in the front:**

```
const baseURL="http://localhost:8000";
axios.defaults.withCredentials=true;
const API=axios.create({
    baseURL,
});
export const signIn=(formData)=>API.post('/authentication/signin',formData);
export const login=(formData)=>API.post('/authentication/login',formData);
```

**My api calling using redux thunk inside my slice:**

```
export const signup=createAsyncThunk('auth/signup',async({formData},{fulfillWithValue,rejectWithValue})=>{
    try{
     const response=await api.login(formData);
     console.log(response.token);
    
    return fulfillWithValue(response.token);
    }catch(err){
        rejectWithValue(err.response.data)
    }
})
```

**My backend cors settings:**

```
   app.use(cors())
```

**Also my backend login function:**

```
export const signUser=catchAsync(async(req,res,next)=>{
  const email=req.body.email;
  const password=req.body.password;
  if(!email||!password){
   return next(new ErrorHandling('You did not entered user name or password',404));
  }
  const user=await User.findOne({email}).select('+password');
  if(!user||!(await user.correctPassword(password,user.password))){
    return next(new ErrorHandling('User name or password are incorrect',400));
  }
    const token=jsonwebtoken.sign({id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{ 
 expiresIn:process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN} );
    const cookieOptions={
        onlyHttp:true
    }
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV=='production'){
        cookieOptions.secure=true;
        cookieOptions.expires=new Date(Date.now()+1000*60)  //Will expires within an hour
    }
    res.cookie('jwt',token,cookieOptions);
    return res.status(statusCode).json({
      status:"success",
      token,
      data: user
      
    })

});
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Social media blog application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
..........
```

**My index.js file inside my backend:**

```
const app=express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
   app.use(cors())
dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'})
let database=process.env.DATABASE;
const port= process.env.PORT||5000
database=process.env.DATABASE.replace('<password>',process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD);

app.use('/post',postRoute);
app.use('/user',userRoute);
app.use('/authentication',authRoute);
app.all('*',(req,res,next)=>{
    next(new ErrorHandling("Can't find results check if path is valid",404));
})
app.use(ErrorController)

let conn=mongoose.connect(database,{
 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useCreateIndex:true,
    // useFindAndModify:false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
        
}).then(data=>{
    if(data){
        console.log("Successfully connected to server");
    }
    else{
        throw new Error("Unable to connect");
    }
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err.message);
})



app.listen(port,()=>{
console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`);
})
```

**Update:**
Thank you very much for the advices, I found that the issue was that body parser was not in the correct place, so I put it last in the list of middlewares in my backend index.js file and it worked

Comment: `cors()` corresponds to the default configuration of the Express's CORS middleware, which doesn't allow credentials. You'll need to allow credentials explicitly. See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the help, I updated what the resolution for the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a proxy! You're requests shouldn't be routed directly to a back-end on a different (`localhost`/development) port! Imagine if you wanted to change the port number the server was running on in development.

There are multiple ways to do this, but here is the react documentation about it all: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/.

For your case, your API code can change to this:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials=true;
const API=axios.create({
    headers:{
        //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":'*',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
});
export const signIn=(formData)=>API.post('/authentication/signin',formData);
export const login=(formData)=>API.post('/authentication/login',formData);
```

And with a proxy in place, you shouldn't need the `Access-Control` in the header and you should have requests going through as if both the client and server were hosted on the same port.

*Note about proxying:* If you have a live server, something reliable that will always be there (e.g. `https://my-app.com/api/`), then you never have to worry about proxies for development. If you're developing both client and back-end at the same time, **then** proxies become a great alternative to disabling CORS and other issues that may arise.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. I should use proxy in addition to what I did or instead of it?

Comment: Let me update my answer! @Jogn1522

Comment: Hey thank you very much, I tried it now but sadly it didn't work, I have no clue why

Comment: Can you update your question, let's figure this out! Can you include the updated code to the client and server @Jogn1522

Comment: Hey, I didn't do anything differently just added to my package.json file "proxy":"http://localhost:3000" also tried to remove the object from my cors object so that is appear app.use(cors()) also tried to remove the headers from my axios.create. I am updating it in my question.

Comment: @Jogn1522 your proxy should be the servers port. it should be `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000",`. Try that.

Comment: And now that I am looking over you question again, can you post more of your server work?

Comment: Hey I tried it too. It brings me the same error, I truely don't understand why. There is any way to get Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be true through my server?

Comment: I need to see more of your server-side code to give a better explanation.

Comment: Hey massive thanks for the help!, I updated what the issue was and in addition use proxy because it is more comfortable

Comment: @Jogn1522 No problem! Did you get the api calls to work? And if you did get it working, can you thumbs up my answer please and thank you! (: